# Is it okay to edit old posts that have been inactive for months?

Tags: discussion, edits

I mean I just edited [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13528958/revisions) that I think could be more useful if the title is improved.
But after I edited the post, it appears to be an active question in the *active* tab for related tag.

I also saw some other posts that I can improve so that those posts can be easier to find in the future.

But the problem is I'm afraid If I edit many posts in a specific tag, in this case Entity Framework since I'm quite interested in this type of questions, those inactive posts will become active ones even though those have been answered. And some users who see it will think it's a new question and then they will try to comment or answer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *improving* old posts. Anyway, there is a "newest" tab users can use to find new posts.

Comment: @Sam, couple days ago I edited an old post (I forgot which one), and then some users left a comment in the question immediately

Comment: And? The point is to build a library of Q/A's. So, if people need to ask for extra info (via comments), or want to share their knowledge by posting an answer, good. They're helping SO to continue growing.

Comment: the asker could have been inactive too and the _active_ tab can't differentiate which ones are a _really active_ or which ones are _active just because it's edited_ sorry, I just not convinced that's why I asked

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357400/is-it-encouraged-to-bump-update-old-answers

Comment: Further information: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/) from the FAQ at Meta.SE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with editing old posts, we even have a few badges for it! (Excavator and Archaeologist).

It's true that editing gives a post a bump. That's fine - new people may take a look at it, post new comments and/or answers, and this information may help a future visitor.

The usual comments apply though:
You should try not to edit too many posts in quick order. As you observed, editing a post bumps it to the front page, and we don't want too many old posts bumped this way after each other.
And, try to fix everything that's wrong with a post. In the case of the linked edit, it looks like you gave an otherwise good post a more specific title, and I think that edit was useful. If the post also had other issues, like "txt spk" or `incorrect use of markdown`, that should have been fixed as well.

Comment: I'll try to edit necessary posts only, this what I thought, it will go to front page and mislead the readers, thanks for the advice..