# Archaeologist rewarding abusive edit behavior again

Tags: discussion, edits, bump

So a user just went and searched for "Thanks in advanced" and bumped [dozens of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122012/juergen?tab=activity&sort=revisions) to the front page.

Nothing else was fixed, and this included unsalvageable off-topic questions.

Could one of the mods contact the user and remind him that [Editing old posts is ok only when it adds value](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268716/is-it-okay-to-edit-old-posts-that-have-been-inactive-for-months/268719#268719) and leaving other problems untouched or bumping off-topic questions does not add value.

I don't think this is the behavior that badges are supposed to reward.

Is this flag-worthy behavior, try to catch the user while active and leave them a comment, or just ignore it?

Comment: It is better to post in meta about the *issue* and not about the *user* to avoid the risk of the meta police to punish the user ([link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268177/1476885)). In this case, I would flag to a mod instead of calling mod attention here in meta.

Comment: Wait, they literally "fixed" 'thanks in advanced' *to 'thanks in advance'*? **Who even does that?** Argh so annoying…!

Comment: @NathanTuggy: He left every question he touched in need of further editing.  Every single one.  (At minimum, the "thanks in advance" should have been deleted, with or without the D)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, I found his most recent edit and commented accordingly after I saw this post.

Comment: Ugh. I feel like a 5 year member with 6k rep should know better than to pull a stunt like this. Edit: And 2 Gold badges for reviewing as well this is pretty blatant.

Comment: I get the feeling there may have been some sort of automation involved with this...

Comment: This question perfectly demonstrates why I think posts like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/288169#288160), which probably started this mess, are actively harmful...

Comment: Hey, I myself did something simmilar, maybe a co-incodence, but today itself. However, I removed the `'thanks in advance(d)(cement)'` wholely and salutation parts and some minor typos, in some cases but nothing much. So does my action counts as  flag-worthy behavior, too?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - if you fixed other aspects of the post then that's OK. It doesn't have to make the post perfect, but as long as it's an improvement then that's good.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks. I was hoping I am right, just needed a conformation.

Comment: The fact that someone purposely went around and edited a bunch of questions to change "Thanks in advanced" to "Thanks in advance" instead of just removing it (even though it's still a bad edit by itself) just makes my skin crawl.

Comment: Maybe this user should be suspended for a day so that he loses his _fanatic_ badge (currently at 99/100)

Comment: I realize trivial flags may fall by the wayside sometimes, but I flagged this user's edits on April 14th and the flag is still sitting as "Pending" as of May 4th.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is flag worthy, and do that rather than posting on meta.

The user is clearly doing something inappropriate here. They have just addressed one issue - quite badly - and left the rest of the post alone.

Unfortunately there's not a lot we can do as moderators here. The user has earned the badge they were after and probably won't do it again.

Comment: Can't you tempban him for a while? Give him a warning? Anything that makes future visitors say "This isn't ok"?

Comment: @Joehot200 - I could send a message and (optionally) suspend, but there's nothing that would be visible to future visitors to say "this is not OK".

Comment: You could ask the developers to turn off the bit of the new profile page that actively encourages people to get badges :-)

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam The new profile page is terrible anyway. For reasons like that, and reasons like it looks horrible, and it generally is just spammed with useless stuff.
Though that's offtopic here, so I shouldn't really rant about it.

Comment: @Joehot200 and yet you have :D

Comment: It was the appearance (and subsequent disappearance) of the archaeologist badge progress from the profile page that brought me here. I agree with its removal - achieving this badge should take the right kind of effort (imho automated tracking of progress encourages lazy behaviors).