# Where is the Archaeologist badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, badge-progress

I remember this badge being among others, but now it's not there:

[image]

Is there an explanation?

Comment: I wondered about this too. I'm guessing here, but it could well have been removed from the new badge-tracker because it was [encouraging a lot of trivial edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290528/archaeologist-rewarding-abusive-edit-behavior-again) to old questions.

Comment: I still have Archaeologist as my currently tracked badge on SO.

Comment: @Jeffrey, then don't untrack it unless you're ready to lose your ability to track it again ;) I wasn't tracking it and it doesn't appear for me either, even in the "All" view.

Comment: [Here's the link to get progress on Archaeologist Badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158831/archaeologist-badge-advancement)

Comment: It still have been awarded 9 hours ago on StackOverFlow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist

Comment: You gotta dig deep to find it.

Comment: @Soma that is because it isn't the badge that has been removed, but the UI on the profile page that indicates your current progress.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

Filtering out some badges (for sites that have been around less then 6 months) caused the bug - turns out not all sites have complete history records.

Comment: What about [Excavator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/excavator)? I don't see it anywhere to track it.

Comment: Yeah, same issue. Next build ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a guess, but it may be a side-effect after resolving [this issue about unobtainable time-dependant badges for young StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253497/284991).

[I've warned them there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list#comment833458_253497). Let's see if it's related or not.

---

***Edit:***

Apparently, [it might be related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list#comment833459_253497), but they're still looking on it.

---

***Edit:***

Yeah, [my feeling was right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292393/1064325). Thanks, ZygD for reporting, and thanks Oded for fixing!

Comment: BTW, the badge doesn't appear anymore for me, also.