# Is it encouraged to bump (update) old answers

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, bump

**Note:** These answers are not wrong or outdated, they can just use improvement like: adding links to documentation, better formatting and maybe even more efficient code.

---

I have plenty of old answers that could use a touch up but there are 2 issues:

1. Some of these questions are quite specific so I doubt if the answer would help anyone but the OP
2. It will bump the question

These problems in combination with each other arise the question *Is it encouraged to update old answers?* As it will bump them and they might not be of use.

---

*The reason I'm asking is because I have seen people complain about bumps before and I want to get the **community** standpoint on this*

Comment: If you're really going to make the post more valuable to future users by making a significant enough change that doesn't change the meaning of the post drastically, then i see no problem with it. Just don't go crazy. I've updated old **popular** answers of mine a few times, but only to add more up to date information with version releases or something that I feel would benefit future users. If the Q&A gets little traffic though, I'd maybe leave it alone.

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for the advice! I will most likely update them and good thinking looking at the current traffic I think I will copy that behavior :)

Comment: Bumping would only be a problem if you sat down and batch-updated 50+ old answers all at one time. That's not really the issue here. The question is, would your edit *improve* the answer, or *change* the answer? Improvement is great. Drastic changes require more care.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated

Comment: @CodyGray Understood, I will keep it at 49 edits at a time :)

Comment: In all seriousness, you have to consider the scale of SO and *why* people find mass edits disruptive. The problem is that many of us use the home page ("interesting" tab) to find...interesting questions to answer. That draws from recently-active questions with tags the system thinks are interesting to us. Normally, it's filled with new questions that still need an answer. But if you go edit a bunch of old posts, then those show up as "interesting" when they're really not meriting our attention. One or two edits are a drop in the ocean. A large number of rapid-fire edits are a DoS attack.

Comment: @CodyGray I understand, I will make sure I won't flood active. You can post this as an answer if you'd like (as this does actually answer the question)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I don't know about everyone else in the community, but I strongly encourage you to update your answers any time you discover that there is a way to improve their quality. "Bumped" posts on the front page only last a few minutes. Quality answers last years.

I try to keep all my answers up to date. It often happens that when one gets an upvote and I reread it, I will fix grammar or spelling that I had missed before. When I get a comment telling me something isn't working, I often add the question to a list of things to recheck later. If there is an API update, I will sometimes search for multiple of my related answers to update at the same time.

Do things that improve the quality of the site. Don't worry about bumping.

Comment: and bumping is only visible by the ones who enable "active" questions, not "newest", which is very difficult to follow when filtering on popular tags like python, c or java.

Comment: Agreed. The suggestion that you should not improve the quality of an answer is crazy to me. Yes, it will be "bumped", but if that's a problem then fix the bumping algorithm - it is not a capricious force to be worked around.

Answer (score -1):

> Some of these questions are quite specific so I doubt if the answer would help anyone but the OP

If you think that the post isn't going to be useful to other people, then you can reflect that opinion with a downvote.

If you can edit a post such that it will be useful to other people after you've finished editing it, then improving it is helpful, but if the post still isn't going to be useful even after your edit, you're just wasting your time and others', so don't edit such a post, just leave it.

> they can just use improvement like: [...] more efficient code.

If you believe you have an alternate solution to a problem that you think is superior than an existing answer, you should post your new solution as a new answer, not edit someone else's answer to use the solution you think is better.  If your answer ends up being a derived work of another answer, be sure to cite that other answer appropriately to indicate what is your original contribution and what is the work of that other author.

As to other changes, keep in mind that if you're going to edit an older post I'd hold yourself to a higher bar as far as how much the edit should improve the post.  Also consider the value of the post (both before and after the edit).  Editing a post that barely meets the minimum standards of acceptability and that not many people have found useful, and fixing a typo or a formatting problem, isn't adding a lot of value, while editing a canonical post that's frequently used as a reference is much more valuable, and can be worth the minor disruption of having other users ensure that the edit is appropriate.

Finally, as has been mentioned in comments, try not to make a large number of edits in a short period of time, particularly when editing old posts, as this ends up being much more disruptive to other users than having one or two posts edited at a time.

Comment: Just an observation - I agree with your points but I don't think some of them actually apply here, because the OP is talking about *their own answers*.